# How to limit memory usage by libjpeg

Tags: ios, libjpeg

Short version: iOS's `UIImageJPEGRepresentation()` crashes on large images. I'm trying to use & modify libjpeg to respect the `max_memory_to_use` field, which it's ignoring.

Long version: I'm writing an iOS app which crashes when converting a large image to JPEG after prolonged usage reduces available memory (a trickling leak involving quirks of `@autoreleasepool{}`, but we're addressing that separately). For images captured by the device camera (normal use, actual size) `UIImageJPEGRepresentation()` can require up to 200MB (!), crashing if not available. This is a problem with `UIImageJPEGRepresentation()` which a web search shows goes back for years and seems unsolved; filing a tech support request with Apple elicits "file a bug report" which doesn't solve my immediate customer needs.

To resolve this, I'm bypassing `UIImageJPEGRepresentation()` by using libjpeg (http://www.ijg.org) and digging into its operation, which shows exactly the same problem (presumably Apple uses it in iOS). libjpeg does provide a means to specify maximum memory usage via the parameter `max_memory_to_use` a la:

```
struct jpeg_compress_struct cinco;
cinfo.mem->max_memory_to_use = 10*1024*1024;
```

which would be used by the libjpeg function `jpeg_mem_available (j_common_ptr cinfo, long min_bytes_needed, long max_bytes_needed, long already_allocated)` (in jmemnobs.c) but, in the standard implementation, is completely ignored (comment even says `Here we always say, "we got all you want bud!"`). Blender has altered the function (http://download.blender.org/source/chest/blender_2.03_tree/jpeg/jmemmac.c) to respect the parameter, but seems I'm missing something to make it work in my app or it's just being ignored anyway elsewhere.

So: how does one modify jmemnobs.c in libjpeg to actually & seriously respect memory limitations, rather than jokingly ignore them?

Comment: Did you try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20244782/uiimagejpegrepresentation-taking-huge-memory) first ?

Comment: Yes. The memory spike happens during the `CGContextDrawImage()` call. Near as I can tell, iOS uses libjpeg to do the conversion; whether a single call for the whole image or one line at a time, `jpeg_write_scanlines()` allocates a huge amount of memory just like `CGContextDrawImage()` and `UIImageJPEGRepresentation()` (which presumably just does what your link shows).